# Bind function to Ajax Form Success Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to call a function with a conversion tag when a form is successfully submitted via ajax.

Since the Javascript for handling the form is generated by the CMS of the site I am not able to change it. I don't want to rewrite the whole ajax call and just call my function when the form successfully submits

This is the Javascript Code generated by the CMS (it's just a snippet)

```
qpzP: function(e, t, n) {
            "use strict";
            Object.defineProperty(t, "__esModule", {
                value: !0
            });
            var r = n("ZClI"),
                i = (window.ElementFormContainer || window.ElementBase).extend({
                    $form: null,
                    ajax: !0,
                    time: null,
                    wakeup: function() {
                        return this.time = new Date, this.$form = this.getViewport().jQuery("> form", this.$element[0]), this.$form.on("submit", function(e) {
                            this.ajax && (e.preventDefault(), this.submit())
                        }.bind(this)), this
                    },
                    submit: function() {
                        if ("undefined" != typeof cms && cms) return !1;
                        if (!this.ajax) return this.$form.submit(), this;
                        var e = $('input[type="file"]:not([disabled])', this.$form);
                        e.each(function(e, t) {
                            t.files.length > 0 || $(t).prop("disabled", !0)
                        });
                        var t = new FormData(this.$form[0]);
                        "undefined" != typeof webcard && "culture" in webcard && webcard.culture && t.append("culture", webcard.culture), e.prop("disabled", !1), t.append("id", this.getId()), t.append("tac", Math.floor(((new Date).getTime() - this.time.getTime()) / 1e3));
                        var n = "" != this.$form.attr("action") ? this.$form.attr("action") : "/form_container/submit";
                        return $.ajax({
                            url: n,
                            data: t,
                            processData: !1,
                            contentType: !1,
                            type: "POST",
                            success: function(e) {
                                this.$element.find(".ed-element").each(function() {
                                    this.element.destroy()
                                }), this.$element.html(e), $(e).is(".wv-success") ? this.getViewport().notify("form.success", [this, this.$form]) : this.getViewport().notify("form.error", [this, this.$form]), this.wakeup();
                                var t = this.$element.find(".ed-element"),
                                    n = [];
                                t.each(function(e, t) {
                                    var i = r.a.getTypeClassName($(t).attr("class"));
                                    i in window && n.push(new window[i](t))
                                }.bind(this)), animations.initSubsequent(n)
                            }.bind(this)
                        }), this
                    },
                    setAjax: function(e) {
                        return this.ajax = e, this
                    }
                });
            t.default = i
        },
```

This is what I though could work:

```
/* Conversion Tracking */
$(function () {
    $('form').bind('submit', function () {
        gtag('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': 'AW-xxx/xxx'});
        console.log('gtracking_sent');

    });

});
```

But it doesn't work.
Ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Well, I think the above code snippet is executed, when you submit the form on the page.

Comment: Well, if you check the wakup function in the code snippet, you see that it is prevented

Comment: oh right, sorry, only read the code you posted at the end, that first code is indecipherable gibberish to me - comments reomved

Comment: Yea, I think the same, but maybe there's something in it which can help me add a hook/callback, idk